# Quartz.net fail-over setup : Incorrect first run of the job

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I successfully set up a two node scheduler cluster to execute a job. I used **OracleODP-20** connector to connect to oracle database, where the **QRTZ_** tables are created. Job scheduled is also getting executed by either one of the scheduler in every 5 minutes.

This is my trigger:

```
ISimpleTrigger trigger = (ISimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                                          .WithIdentity("mytrigger", schedId)
                                                          .StartNow()
                                                          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithRepeatCount(-1).WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
                                                          .Build();
```

But there is one problem.When the scheduler is starting up, it always executes
the job, even if time for the next execution of the job is not now.

e.g.,

- Job1 will run every 5 minutes.
- Scheduler1 started at 10.00 and it
  executes the Job1 and is waiting for 10.05 for the next execution.
- When i start Scheduler2 at 10.01, even though Job1 was supposed to
  run next 10.05, it will run at 10.01

After this initial run, the Job1 will be executed by only one of the scheduler and it goes fine.

But I am not sure how to tell
the Scheduler2 that, the job is already executed by Scheduler1 and don't execute it till the next fire time.

Any help in this?

Comment: You have configured job store as clustered?
<add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true"/>

Comment: I have done that. Quartz is working properly in cluster. The only issue is with the first execution time

Comment: The steps I put in the e.g will explain that

Comment: And you have created this trigger only once, not on each node's startup? I see that you trigger contains instance's id as group which is very suspicious. It seems that you are having trigger for each node when you should have just single trigger created if it does not exist yet.

Comment: oh I see. I understood my mistake. Thanks for your help. I will see how I can get an existing trigger for a job. :) I can accept this as answer if you put this as answer.

Comment: But, one more thing.Even though I am creating a trigger for each node I can see only one trigger when i run `select * from qrtz_simple_triggers`

Comment: Do you have fixed instance id then? You should have separate instance ids for each node. Instance id strategy AUTO is quite good default.

Comment: ya. i have used AUTO as instance id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create this trigger only once, not on each node's startup.

I see that you trigger contains instance's id as group which is very suspicious. It seems that you are having trigger for each node when you should have just single trigger created if it does not exist yet.

Easier to read trigger definition would thus be:

```
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();

var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<NoOpJob>().Build();

var key = new TriggerKey("trigger-name", "trigger-group");
if (sched.GetTrigger(key) == null)
{
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity(key)
        .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenHourDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow))
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .RepeatForever()
            .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
        .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}
```

I threw in the even hour date to get more precise timings instead of 'from now every 5 minutes'. You could easily get this with cron trigger too.